# Is the problem VIII, 1.6 of Dungundji's Topology right?

Tags: general-topology

On the page 178 of Dungundji's Topology,

Problem 6 of Section 1 says:

A **grating** of a space $Y$ is a family $\{V_{\alpha}\;|\;\alpha \in A\}$ of disjoint open sets such that $\{\overline{V_{\alpha}}\;|\;\alpha \in A\}$ is a covering of $Y$ and $\;Int(\overline{V_{\alpha}}) = V_{\alpha}\;$ for each $\alpha \in A.\;$ Let $\{V_{\alpha}\;|\;\alpha \in A\}$ and $\{W_{\beta}\;|\;\beta \in B\}$ be two gratings of $Y$. Prove:
$$\{V_{\alpha}\cap W_{\beta}\;|\;(\alpha, \beta) \in A\times B\}$$
is a grating of $Y$.

So far I've succeeded in proving $$Int(\overline{V_{\alpha}\cap W_{\beta}}) = V_{\alpha}\cap W_{\beta} \quad\forall \alpha, \beta$$, but couldn't prove $\{\overline{V_{\alpha}\cap W_{\beta}}\;|\;(\alpha, \beta) \in A\times B\}$ covers $Y$ using given conditions only.



My question is: Is the statement of the problem right? I think $\{(-\infty,0), (1, \infty)\}\cup\{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})\;|\;n \in \mathbf{N}\}$ and $\{(-\infty,-1), (0, \infty)\}\cup\{(-\frac{1}{n},-\frac{1}{n+1})\;|\;n \in \mathbf{N}\}$ are both gratings of $\mathbf{R}$, but their intersection

$$\{(-\infty,-1), (1,\infty)\}\bigcup\left\{(-\frac{1}{n},-\frac{1}{n+1})\;\big|\;n \in \mathbf{N}\right\}\bigcup\left\{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})\;\big|\;n \in \mathbf{N}\right\}$$
is not a grating since $0$ does not belong to any of their closures. Am I thinking right? Or is there a way to prove coveredness of $Y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right.

This would be true if $(V_\alpha)_\alpha$ and $(W_\beta)_\beta$ had the property that for any $\alpha,\beta$, we have $\overline{V_\alpha\cap W_\beta}=\overline{V_\alpha}\cap \overline{W_\beta}$, but in your example, it is clearly not the case, as $(-1,0)\cap (0,1)=\emptyset$, but their closures intersect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: @user609441: If you like an answer, you should upvote it by pressing the up arrow (and if you think it's the best one, you should also mark it as accepted, by clicking the ✓ symbol below).